# What is the difference between Azul OpenJDK, Zulu OpenJDK and OpenJDK?

Tags: java, azul-zulu

What is the difference between Azul OpenJDK, Zulu OpenJDK and OpenJDK?

Answer (score 185):

## Update 2021-09

- For versions 8 through 16, Oracle required a fee if their own *Oracle JDK* product was used in production, but not for dev, test, and training usages.
- For Java 17, the [Oracle JDK](https://www.oracle.com/javadownload) product is available under  a new
  [*No-Fee Terms and Conditions*](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/licenses/no-fee-license.html) license, [discussed on the Oracle
  company blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/cloud-infrastructure/post/introducing-free-java-license).

On my first reading, it appears this new license makes production use free-of-cost (along with dev, test, and training usages), **except for products sold for a fee while bundling the Oracle JDK** product. But I am not an attorney, so read the terms yourself and consult legal advice as needed.

Keep in mind that many other vendors continue to provide implementations of the Java specs, as shown in the flowchart below. Some of these vendors sell support plans, either optionally or as a requirement for use of their product. Never assume, always read the detailed requirements for any distribution you obtain.

Another 2021 update: Add Microsoft to the list of vendors seen below.

---

## Java specification versus implementation

Java is defined by a [set of specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), [JSRs](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/overview), and [JEPs](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/0), all published by Oracle.

Those specifications are implemented in the source code found at the [*OpenJDK*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project.

Several vendors provide builds of that source code. Some charge money for those builds and some do not.

[Azul Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems) is one such vendor, a company  providing multiple implementations. [*Zulu Community*](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-community/) is one, provided free of charge. [*Zulu Enterprise*](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-enterprise/) is another of their products, a commercial offering. [*Zing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems#Zing_JVM) is yet another product of theirs, a JVM/JDK for special needs.

Other JDK product vendors include SAP, Amazon, Microsoft, Oracle, BellSoft, Adoptium, Red Hat, IBM, Linux “apt get”, FreeBSD “Ports and Packages”, and more.

You asked:

> Is there any practical difference between Azul OpenJDK, Zulu OpenJDK and OpenJDK?

Yes and no.

Firstly, **OpenJDK provides only [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code)**. So you cannot use OpenJDK to run Java apps. You must first build the OpenJDK source code yourself to get [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) for your particular host platform, or you must rely on a vendor make a build for you. As seen in the flow chart below, there are several such vendors making builds of the OpenJDK source code.

As for products from Azul Systems, there is no such thing as *Azul OpenJDK* nor *Zulu OpenJDK* that I know of. Azul offers multiple products, as discussed above, but none of them by that name.

The `Zulu` name is used for 3 products, the *Community* and *Enterprise* editions above, plus [*Zulu Embedded*](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-embedded/) for running on constrained hardware resources. As explained on their web site, all three of these are builds of the source code from OpenJDK.

So, no, basically no practical differences, as they all are builds of OpenJDK, and behave similar to most any other build of OpenJDK source code. Any desktop, server, or console application written to comply with the Java specifications will run on *Zulu Community* and *Zulu Enterprise*.

But, yes, there are some differences in that Azul adds some features such as having back-ported Flight Recorder and Mission Control to their Java 8 version of Zulu products. And Azul, like any such JDK provider, reserves the right to add a patch when urgently needed to fix a critical bug or security vulnerability without waiting for a release in the OpenJDK codebase.

And, yes, there are major differences with the *Zing* product by Azul as that is intended for special needs such as supporting very large amounts of memory. While I presume this product uses parts of OpenJDK, Zing performs quite differently to meet those special needs while still conforming with the Java specifications to be able to run any application written in Java.

Another practical difference is that you can obtain support services from Azul Systems for their builds. Several of the vendors provide support services for their builds. OpenJDK provides only source code, no support.

Lastly, I should mention that Azul Systems is [one of the sponsors](https://www.eclipse.org/membership/exploreMembership.php) of [*Adoptium*](https://adoptium.net/) (formerly known as *AdoptOpenJDK*), a project at the [Eclipse Foundation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Foundation). Adoptium provides (a) builds of OpenJDK, and (b) [test suites for quality assurance](https://medium.com/adoptopenjdk/the-first-drop-introducing-adoptopenjdk-quality-assurance-aqa-v1-0-fe09f10ced80).

If you have specific product questions, you should study the Azul.com web site, and contact the sales department at Azul Systems. I speak only for myself here, unaffiliated with that company. I have on occasion used their *Zulu Community* product, but not the others.

➥ Read [*Java is Still Free*](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-2-0-0-6b9aa8d6d244) to understand the ecosystem of Oracle, OpenJDK, and the various vendors of Java implementations.

---

Here is a flow chart I made to help guide you in choosing a vendor for an implementation of Java 11.

[image: Flowchart guiding you in choosing a vendor for a Java 11 implementation]

Comment: Oracle do not publish either JSRs or JEPs. Java Specification Requests are published by the Java Community Process (JCP). JDK Enhancement Proposals are published on the OpenJDK project. Anyone who has committer status on OpenJDK can submit a JEP.

Comment: @Speakjava At the bottom of every JSR page and every JEP page you will find a copyright claim by Oracle Corporation.

Comment: @skomisa I added much more discussion to address that. Thanks for the criticism.

Comment: My poor wording since it was intended as feedback rather than criticism. (I'm astounded at the level of detail in your answer.)

Comment: @BasilBourque this flowchart is fantastic! Can you update this for 2024 due to the fact that Java 21 is now available. With Java 21, there are some significant features available: virtual threads/coroutines, records, pattern matching, the vector API in its 7th incubation (JEP 448), etc.

Comment: @Alan Thanks for the feedback. I don’t see how Java 21, or its features you listed, affect this flow chart. Please explain. The chart still seems correct and applicable today, except (a) some vendors *do* produce a JRE, and (b) Microsoft’s offering should be added.

Comment: I think the branch "Exploit: FPGAs and GPUs" might need to be rethought if the Vector API actually allows results in bytecode or machine code that uses the GPU  to compute vectors That will obviously impact ML libraries. The branch for "Coroutines" is now generally available to anyone, not just Dragonwell.

Answer (score 48):

Let's start with full disclosure, I work for Azul (which I think makes me qualified to answer the question).

OpenJDK is a "...place to collaborate on an open-source implementation of the Java Platform, Standard Edition, and related projects".  Primarily, it hosts the source code repositories for the versions of Java since JDK 6.  Sun open-sourced their implementation of JDK 7 in 2007, which was how OpenJDK originated.  Subsequently, a project was created for JDK 6 (which oddly, is based on JDK 7).  Each version since then has been developed through the OpenJDK.

Azul is a company that specialises in Java and JVM products.

Zulu is the name chosen for the binary distribution of the OpenJDK provided by Azul.  This comes in three versions:

1. Zulu Community: The free distribution provided under the GPLv2 with classpath exception (CPE) license.
2. Zulu Enterprise: A commercially supported binary distribution with SLAs for how quickly updates will be made available after Oracle provide theirs, two versions of each update (CPU and PSU) and phone/e-mail bug reporting/resolution.
3. Zulu Embedded: Porting and support for specific chipsets and hardware configurations for embedded applications. Also, a commercial product, although free ARM 32 builds are available for Zulu Community.

To summarise, OpenJDK is the source code, Azul is the company and Zulu is the binary distribution built from OpenJDK.

Comment: Zulu Embedded can you for Android System?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no Zulu Embedded for Android.

Comment: @Speakjava: so what is [Azul Zulu Prime builds of OpenJDK](https://www.azul.com/products/components/azul-zulu-prime-builds-of-openjdk/) then? According to its feature set it seems to be the same like [Azul Platform Prime](https://www.azul.com/products/prime/) (formerly known as Azul Zing) although according to its name it pretends to be a "*binary distribution built from OpenJDK*" as you call it in your comment?

Comment: @VolkerSimonis, the simplest explanation is that Zulu is the name of our JDK distribution that is based on OpenJDK. Zulu Community/Core are our builds of OpenJDK (without functional modification). Zulu Prime (which used to be Zing) is a JDK built from OpenJDK but with functional changes (GC and JIT compiler). All our builds from JDK 8 onwards pass the TCK so fully conform to the relevant Java SE standard. The short answer that this was a branding change.

Comment: @Speakjava, thanks for your answer. So am I right that if "Zulu Prime" is  "_based on_" and "_built from OpenJDK_" which is licensed under GPLv2 plus CPE then "Zulu Prime" and all of its functional changes like GC and JIT compiler must be made available under the very same license (i.e. GPLv2 plus CPE)?