# Jenv - same java version but with prefix

Tags: java, jenv

When I run `jenv versions`, it shows below options

```
  11.0
  11.0.21
  17.0
  17.0.9
  21.0
  21.0.1
  zulu64-11.0.21
  zulu64-17.0.9
  zulu64-21.0.1
```

What's the difference between `11.0.21` and `zulu64-11.0.21` and which one should I choose?

The latter has the prefix `zulu64-` whereas former doesn't have any prefix.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Azul OpenJDK, Zulu OpenJDK and OpenJDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61335109/what-is-the-difference-between-azul-openjdk-zulu-openjdk-and-openjdk)

Comment: @aled I downloaded all my JDKs from https://www.azul.com/downloads/#zulu. I still don't understand why there are multiple JDK distributions installed in my machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the way Jenv works. It shows the exact version (example 17.0.9), the major version in case you want to just select a major only (example 17.0). Additionally it adds to the list the version with the vendor prefix (example zulu64-17.0.9). So a single JDK install adds 3 times to the list.

This is all to give the user flexibility to select versions in different ways considering they may have multiple parallel installations from different vendors/versions.

Reference: https://github.com/jenv/jenv/issues/136

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61335109/what-is-the-difference-between-azul-openjdk-zulu-openjdk-and-openjdk). But the short answer, is that you have different JDK distributions installed.